# Create mulitple files with autocomments inserted using Vim

Tags: vim

How do i create a multiple c files with the following comments appended in all newly created files with their respective filenames in file field as shown below. filesNames : `f1.c` `f2.c` till `f10.c`

```
/*********
* file: filename.c
* Author : powernest
* Copyright
* .....
*********/
```

Comment: Do you want this only once, or all times, whenever you create new C files? How about other filetypes? There are various plugins that provide this, have you searched for them?

Comment: I am not really particular about the filetype, but thought could be  done with vim commands directly.

Answer (score 1):

In other words you need a template with an header for your `c` files.

There are some plugins to manage templates in vim like: [template engine](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2834) and [vim-template](https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template).
The second one, `vim-template` suits well your needs.

With `vim-template` you create a template for your files with the data you need and you can use variables like `%FILE%`

Answer (score 1):

Though I think you're better suited with one of the many *template* plugins, here's a simple one-liner that creates the files, as requested:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | let f = 'f'.i.'.c' | execute 'split' f | call append(0, ['/*********','* file: ' . f,'* Author : powernest','* Copyright','* .....','*********/']) | endfor
```

This uses a loop to generate the filenames, then `:split`s the files, and `append()`s the template contents.